# update new SSD path on dual boot ( windows 11 and zorin)

Tags: dual-boot, zorin

I used to have **two ssd** on my laptop  one with **windows 11 (called in motherboard dev0)** installed on it and the other one have an **(zorin os)** on it **(called in motherboard dev1)**

and i use **dual boot** with **bootloader** of **zorin os** that is **stored in dev1** and **bootloader** of **windows 11** stored in **dev1** and i can easily change between them when i turn on the laptop **via zorin bootup interface**

but the ssd that has windows 11 (**dev0) got damaged** and i **replaced it** with new one that has **it's own windows 11 and bootloader** **( now it's called dev4)**

**the problem** is the **zorin boot** interface **still uses** the **old windows bootloader location** and i couldn't  find way to **replace the old bootloader** location with the **new location**
*my motherboard supports uefi

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [PonJar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/429115/ponjar)'s comment.
I just updated grub using this command: `sudo update-grub` and that fixed my problem.